# No ejecuta un Override de Classes de un Módulo en Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop1.7, override

Instalé el módulo de AliExpress de Línea Gráfica y necesito hacer un override de la class AlliExpressAttribute para que se tenga en cuenta en futuras actualizaciones.

Lo he realizado de mil formas y Prestashop no ejecuta mi Override.
He creado el archivo AlliExpressAttribute.php en:

```
/modules/aliexpress_official/override/classes/AlliExpressAttribute.php

/override/modules/aliexpress_official/classes/AlliExpressAttribute.php

/override/classes/AlliExpressAttribute.php (esta ya por desesperación)
```

El archivo contiene la función *public static function getGroups($id_category)* en la que simplemente comento la parte en la que le especifica a la sentencia SQL el id_category_default, dado que vamos a subir productos en la categoría OFERTAS pero esa no es la categoría por defecto de los productos a subir.

```
<?php

class AliexpressAttributeOverride extends AliexpressAttribute
{
    public static function getGroups($id_category)
    {
        $id_lang = Context::getContext()->language->id;
        $id_shop = AliexpressConf::getShopId();
        $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT fl.`id_feature`, fl.`name` FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'feature_lang` fl
            JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'feature` f
                ON f.`id_feature` = fl.`id_feature`
            JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'feature_value` fv
                ON fv.`id_feature` = f.`id_feature`
            JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'feature_product` fp
                ON fp.`id_feature` = f.`id_feature`
            JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_shop` ps
                ON ps.`id_product` = fp.`id_product`
            WHERE fl.`id_lang` = ' . (int) $id_lang . ' AND ps.`id_shop` = ' . (int) $id_shop;
        /*if ((int) $id_category > 0) {
            $sql .= ' AND ps.`id_category_default` = ' . (int) $id_category;
        }*/

        if ($rows = Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql)) {
            foreach ($rows as $k => $row) {
                if ($values = FeatureValue::getFeatureValuesWithLang($id_lang, $row['id_feature'])) {
                    $rows[$k]['values'] = $values;
                } else {
                    $rows[$k]['values'] = array();
                }
            }
            return $rows;
        }
        return array();
    }
}
```

He borrado mil veces la caché, tanto en **Rendimiento > Borrar caché**, como por SSH eliminando la carpeta */var/cache/* y todo sigue igual. Tengo la reconfiguración de las plantillas cuando se actualizan, Cache: No y Modo depuración: Sí.

¿Hay algo que se me escapa?

Versión de Prestashop: 1.7.6.4

Gracias de antemano. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo visto, para los módulos, Prestashop solo hace override de su clase principal. En este caso solo se puede hacer override de aliexpress_official.php que se encuentra en /modules/aliexpress_official/

Un saludo.